# issue with welcome/leave messages

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_memeber_join(member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("449873043913834506")
    await bot.send_message(channel, "'''{} has joined.'''".format(user.name))
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="UNRANK")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)

@bot.event
async def on_memeber_leave(member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("449873043913834506")
    await bot.send_message(channel, "'''{} has left. '''".format(user.name))
```

This is my code and i don't know what is the problem.
There's no errors found in the console, but the bot sends nothing when someone has joined or left.

Comment: Are you using discord rewrite or the regular version of discord.py?

Comment: Do you have some error handler that could be suppressing error messages?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, the thing with discord.py is it usually wont tell you what goes wrong if everything "works" chances are everything is done right (kind of) But it isn't really correct. Because of this it wont bring up any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the discord.py code, can the problem be your spelling of `member` in `on_memeber_join` and `on_memeber_leave`?

Answer (score 0):

The names of your events must match exactly with the names in the [event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join).  Change the names here to `on_member_join` and `on_member_remove`